# Finding discrepancies in SQL (tricky situation)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a hard time trying to get a specific result.

I have 2 tables, `USERS` and `ADDRESSES`.

Every customer can have multiple addresses related to it's particular `account_number`, take a look:

Table `USERS` (`ID int, ACCOUNT_NUMBER int, ACCOUNT_NAME varchar(32)`):

```
'1' | '1417'  | 'SUPERMARKET_1'
'2' | '1418'  | 'SUPERMARKET_2'
'3' | '14178' | 'SUPERMARKET_3'
'4' | '1419'  | 'SUPERMARKET_4'
'5' | '1420'  | 'SUPERMARKET_5'
```

Table `ADDRESSES` (`ADDRESS_ID int, ACCOUNT_NUMBER int, ADDRESS_NAME varchar(32), ADDRESS_ORG_ID int, ADDRESS_TYPE varchar(32)`)

```
'78979' | '1417'  | '1st Street 4785'   | '787'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78980' | '1417'  | '1st Street 4785'   | '788'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78981' | '1418'  | '1st Street 0012'   | '787'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78982' | '1418'  | '1st Street 0012'   | '788'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78983' | '14178' | '1st Street 478455' | '787'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78984' | '1419'  | '1st Street 0778'   | '788'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78985' | '1420'  | '1st Street 78'     | '787'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78986' | '1420'  | '1st Street 78'     | '788'   | 'SHIPPING_TO'
```

I can have two different `ADDRESS_ORG_ID` : 787 and 788

Every `USER` must have the same number of SHIPPING addresses for each `ADDRESS_ORG_ID`.

Here is my [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcdfe/1)

I would like to obtain those USERS that don't have the same number; I mean, this output:

```
'78983' | '14178' | '1st Street 478455' | '787' | 'SHIPPING_TO'
'78984' | '1419'  | '1st Street 0778'   | '788' | 'SHIPPING_TO'
```

It means, if a customer have two shipping addresses related to the `ADDRESS_ORG_ID = 787` it **MUST HAVE** the same number for the another `ADDRESS_ORG_ID = 788`

I've tried but i did not get a good result, can help me with this?

**Note:** I'm using an Oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to obtain those USERS that don't have the same quantity

If you only care about those two orgs, you can use:

```
select id, 
       sum(case when address_org_id = 787 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_787,
       sum(case when address_org_id = 788 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_788
from ADDRESSES a INNER JOIN
     USERS u
     ON a.account_number = u.account_number
group by id
having sum(case when address_org_id = 787 then 1 else 0 end) <>
       sum(case when address_org_id = 788 then 1 else 0 end) ;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcdfe/6) is a db<>fiddle.

This is based on your question which is about *users*.  You provide results that appear to be at the address level.  You can join the address table back in for that type of information -- or use `listagg()` and other aggregation functions.

Comment: Hey Gordon, thank you very much for replying!
I'm checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Below query must help you,

```
select * from addresses ad
where ad.account_number in (select a.account_number
from ADDRESSES a
group by a.account_number
having sum(DECODE(address_org_id, 787, 1,0)) <>
       sum(DECODE(address_org_id, 788, 1,0)));
```

Cheers !!

> PS - Even the subquery makes you reach till your desired filter.
>   However superquery would help you to gain your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function to get all data(all columns) from the `ADDRESSES` table who don't have same number of addresses.

```
SELECT ADDRESS_ID,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,ADDRESS_NAME,ADDRESS_ORG_ID, ADDRESS_TYPE
FROM
(select a.*, 
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_ORG_ID = 787 THEN 1 END) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER),0) AS CNT787,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_ORG_ID = 788 THEN 1 END) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER),0) AS CNT788
   from ADDRESSES a)
WHERE CNT787 <> CNT788
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcdfe/57)